# How to resume a interrupt download with RandomAccessFile？

Tags: java, download, randomaccessfile

I want to a interrupt download with RandomAccessFile. Here is the code

```
HttpGet httpget = HttpUtil.buildGet(URL)
httpget.setHeader("RANGE", "bytes=" + (position) + "-");
CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClients.createDefault().execute(httpget) 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

int totalLen = 0;
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
RandomAccessFile writeFile = new RandomAccessFile(desc, "rw");
writeFile.seek(position);
byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
totalLen = 0;
int len = is.read(buf);
while (len > 0) {
   totalLen += len;
   writeFile.write(buf);
   len = is.read(buf);
}
response.close();
is.close();
writeFile.close();
```

The HttpRequest return 206 and the download success completed,But I get a wrong file,The file is much bigger than the source and I cant open it.
What's wrong with this code?And how to resume a interrupt download with RandomAccessFile？

Comment: Are you sure the server supports `Range` requests? If it does, the response would include `Accept-Ranges: bytes` for that resource, even if `Range` wasn't given in request header. For a request with a `Range` header, the response would include a `Content-Range` header specifying the range it's actually returning. Your code needs to check the header values. See e.g. here to learn about [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

Comment: Yse,I'm sure  the server supports Range requests.  The response  header include `Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Comment: And what did the `Content-Range` header say in the response?

Comment: `Accept-Ranges: bytes` `ETag: W/"243174107-1583744547157"` `Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 09:02:27 GMT` `Content-Range: bytes 32243658-243174106/243174107` `Content-Type: application/zip`   `Content-Length: 210930449` .    The variable  `position` = 32243658.   I think it's a normal response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075227/how-to-resume-a-interrupt-download-with-randomaccessfile?noredirect=1#comment108052236_61075227):

> ```
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> ETag: W/"243174107-1583744547157"
> Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 09:02:27 GMT
> Content-Range: bytes 32243658-243174106/243174107
> Content-Type: application/zip
> Content-Length: 210930449
> ```

The request specified a starting position of `32,243,658`, and downloaded the remaining `210,930,449` bytes, ending up with a file with `243,174,107` bytes.

Well no, it ended up with a file with *at least* `243,204,042` bytes, i.e. `29,935` bytes too many, because the code always writes the **full** `buffer`, even if the buffer wasn't read in full.

It's very likely that the file is a lot bigger than that, because the data is coming over the network in smaller chunks, so it's likely that the buffer isn't filled with `65,536` bytes on many of the `read()` call.

`read()` returns a `len` value for a reason. Your code should be:

```
writeFile.write(buf, 0, len);
```

Also, you should use try-with-resources, and it's common to inline the `read()` call, so it's not repeated, e.g. code should be:

```
int totalLen = 0;
try (RandomAccessFile writeFile = new RandomAccessFile(desc, "rw")) {
    writeFile.seek(position); // should use value from response header here, not requested value
    try (InputStream is = entity.getContent()) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
        for (int len; (len = is.read(buf)) > 0; ) {
            totalLen += len;
            writeFile.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
response.close();
```